# Quartz Cron Expression: Run Job Every 1 hr 10 minutes 20 seconds starting NOW (immediately)

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I want to run a job every 1 hr 10 minutes and 20 seconds.

For this i have tried with the following cron expression.

```
"0/4220 * * * * ?"
```

But I cannot set more than 60 seconds.
what will be the cron expression for the above need?

Comment: Here's Quartz's official doc about cron expressions: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html and about `SimpleTrigger` which suits you best http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Quartz cron, we can use the simple trigger for this scenario.

In simple trigger we can use based on our need like the following.

We can convert the whole thing as seconds and we can repeat it.

For the 15 minutes and 10 seconds, I have used like the following. Even we can convert in minutes itself.

```
 ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
    .WithIntervalInSeconds(910)
    .RepeatForever()) // note that 10 repeats will give a total of 11 firings
.ForJob(job) // identify job with handle to its JobDetail itself                   
.Build();
```