# Quartz net - Not working as expected

Tags: quartz.net, quartz

I have used the Quartz net expression for the following scenario that
Schedule should run every 40 seconds.

I have added the expression like following.

```
0/40 * * * * ?
```

I expected this to run on every 40 seconds. Instead of that, it runs like,
for the 40th seconds it runs, then it runs when next minutes starts.

[image]

Comment: Refer for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539823/quartz-cron-expression-run-job-every-1-hr-10-minutes-20-seconds-starting-now-i?noredirect=1#comment74213970_43539823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the specifics of Quartz.net but your understanding of what a cron expression does is wrong.

The `/` syntax specifies an increment in the period selected and not a repeat. So you are effectively asking for a job to run at second `0` and second `40` of every minute of every hour of ...

Given what you want, you should use a [simple trigger with a repeat interval](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html).